# Cordova Plug-in cannot find in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to JBoss Hybrid Mobile app & I follow this [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1295913). I have a problem with Cordova Plug-in Discovery, that I cannot find any plug-in listed there (right-click on project --> install Cordova Plug-in), is there any settings that I missed?